# What is the probability that six will show before a one or a two in a consecutive throws of a fair die?

Tags: probability

I am perplexed by an exercise problem I came across yesterday:

In a sequence of consecutive throws of a die, find the probability that six will show before a one or a two.

A.1/6

B.1/2

C.2/3

D.5/6

E.1/3

I am quite confused about this problem.I think A(if I denote the event in the problem as A) is sorta kinda complex, by which I mean, for example, it's probable that both 612 and 12612 are in A.I don't know how to solve this.
My question is:if I change the problem into “the first emerging 6 is before the first emerging 1 or 2”, what is the answer?And if I consider the more complex problem I mentioned above,how should I fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple. Look at the first time, one of the numbers $1,2,6$ occurs.
 Then it is clear that the probability of a $6$ is $\frac {1}{3}$. It does not matter that we do not know how many throws are necessary. The correct answer is therefore E.

Comment: I just upvoted a nice answer which was deleted at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Less elegantly, the probability that none of 1, 2, 6 occur on a particular throw is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the probability that we have $n$ throws with none of 1, 2, 6 occurring, followed by a 6 on the $n+1$st throw is $\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{1}{6}$. So the chance that a 6 occurs first is $\frac{1}{6}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking about the problem:  this can be rephrased as the problem

> Given an unfair coin with $P(H) = \frac{2}{3}$ and $P(T) = \frac{1}{3}$, what is the probability of tossing heads before tails?

To see that this is equivalent, observe that the event $H$ is the event of rolling either a $1$ or a $2$ on a fair die and that the event $T$ is the event of rolling a $6$ on a fair die.  There are other possible outcomes (e.g. $3$, $4$, $5$), but these are ignored (if any of these numbers comes up, the die is rolled again).  There are, therefore, three equiprobable outcomes of interest:  $1$, $2$, and $6$.  This corresponds to the probabilities given above.

Moreover, each die roll is independent of the previous die rolls, so the problem can further be reduced to

> Given an unfair coin with $P(H) = \frac{2}{3}$ and $P(T) = \frac{1}{3}$, what is the probability of tossing tails?

The die is rolled until either event $H$ or event $T$ occurs, which is the same as tossing the unfair coin described.  In order for a $6$ to be rolled before either a $1$ or $2$, the first "valid" coin toss must be a $T$.  This happens with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, which solves the problem.

NB:  This is essentially the same idea as [Peter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/913778/), but I think that it sometimes helps to think about reducing complicated seeming experiments to simpler experiments.

Comment: I have posted this nearly decade-late answer because a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4842196/) was asked today, and I feel like I have *something* to add to the discussion.