# What is the probability of getting at least a 1 or 2 before rolling your first 6?

Tags: probability

so for starters, after $n = 1$ rolls

$n = 1$

$\frac{1}{3}$ since you can get a 1 or 2 on the first try

then $n=2$

$\frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{6}$

However at $n=3$ im a bit confused

I believe it then becomes

$\frac{1}{6}*\frac{3}{4}$

because in those first two rolls, there is $3/4$ chance that one of them is the $\frac{1}{3}$ we want

is this the right way of thinking? how do i carry this on for some abritrary n?

Comment: Suppose you roll a "*large*" number of times... long enough such that every number appears at least once (*guaranteed to eventually happen with probability 1, I leave that to you to justify*).  Now... in this long string of rolls... let us ignore all of it with the exception of the first 1 rolled, the first 2 rolled, and the first 6 rolled.  What orders are possible?  Which of these has the 6 occurring before both the first 1 and the first 2?  Which don't?

Comment: 6 before 1 or 2?
Would that matter, i imagine it goes
a_n * a_n+1 * a_n+2 .... * 1/6

1/6 is when we stop per se, when we land at 6, i want to know if one of those a_n is the 1/3 chance we get 1 or 2

Comment: Yes, I understood the question.  Now, do you understand my hint?

Comment: i made an edit sorry i entered it quickly

Comment: I am trying to imply that thinking in terms of each individual $n$ or $a_n$ is a waste of effort and although could lead to a final correct answer would require far more effort and tedium than it is worth when compared to the far simpler problem "*you have three balls... one labeled with a 1, one labeled with a 2, and one labeled with a 6.  You pull these three balls in sequence without replacement.  What is the probability the ball labeled six was the first ball drawn?*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define the complement event $A$ as 'we didn't get any of 1 and 2 before first 6', then $A_n$ is  'we didn't get any of 1 and 2 before first 6 which was got on the $n$-th rolling', $n\in\mathbb N$.

This way $\mathsf P(A_n) = \frac{1}{6\cdot 2^{n-1}}$  because for $n-1$ rolling we can only have any of $3, 4, 5$ and on the $n$-th we got 6. Total answer:
$$\mathsf P(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf P(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{6\cdot 2^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: why is this the same as the probability of 6 being before 1 and 2?

Comment: @uggupuggu I think I didn't get your question. First of all the dice is fair so there are a lot of symmetry situations in numbers and probabilities. Then it can be just a coincidence

Comment: upon further inspection it appears the answer is actually $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @uggupuggu Yes, exactly :)